# Is there a way to count a page's keywords in Selenium IDE?

Tags: seo, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I'm trying to write a script that checks a page's SEO criteria. I'm a bit stuck with top keyword counts. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the link of the page you are trying to automate? If it isn't available then a screenshot would suffice.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to write a generic script. I want to pass a list of urls through it via sel-blocks.